# How controller determine which view to use in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i just strated with asp.net mvc. My doubt is in a controller we use

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();  

    }
```

so how a relevent view is returned for a particular controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a `Home` controller with an `Index` action here are the default search order locations:

ASP.NET MVC 2:

```
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
```

ASP.NET MVC 3:

```
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

Answer (score 1):

Any MVC tutorial will go over this in the first page or two. I would highly recommend you go through either the [NerdDinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm)tutorial or [Getting Started with MVC3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs) or possibly both.

To answer your question, that will return a view called Index in the Views folder that is named after your controller. In other words, if your view is named HomeController, that will return a view named Index in your Home views folder

Answer (score 0):

The default route in ASP.Net MVC is http://.../Controller/Action. So when you are viewing `Http://localhost/SomeController/Index`, then ASP.Net MVC looks for Index.aspx in designated folders. If it does not find it, then you can see the exception on yellow page that it searched for Index.aspx and Index.ascx in Shared folder and a folder named on your controller.

All this is default behavior and ASP.Net MVC provides you extension points to change some or all of this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the **Function** is used to find the name of the **View**